# videoegg javascript unresponsive script

Tags: javascript, ads

Has anyone ever seen an error similar to this?

"*A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete*"

[image: videoegg javascript error]

The firebug console doesn't show any javascript errors.

Comment: Yes, we have.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when a script has a lot of work to do, or it can happen when the script has a bug. If you suspect that the script has a bug, or if you do not know what script is running, then press the "Stop script" button to stop the script. If you know that some lengthy operation is in progress, then press the Continue button to allow the script to continue working. You might have to do this repeatedly to allow the script to finish.

**Isolate the error further**

If you are using Firefox, you can confirm that the error is indeed the JavaScript script by running Firefox in [safe mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode).

**Further research:**

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unresponsive_Script_Warning

**Profile the script**

From what we see on the screenshot we could suspect that the error is not a firefox extension issue, so running firefox on safe mode may not solve the problem. We also know that the video ads served by video egg may take some time to load.

Use Firebug's [profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) to see how much time that particular video egg script is taking.